# How to use java8 sorting stream to specify a value to rank first

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

How to use java8 sorting steam to specify a value to rank first。
For example：

```
@Test
void test(){
    User user = new User("CJ",98);
    User user1 = new User("Tom",90);
    User user2 = new User("lucy",85);
    User user3 = new User("James",83);
    List<User> list = Lists.newArrayList(user,user1,user2,user3);
    list = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getGrade).reversed()).sorted((o1,o2)->{
        if(o2.getName().equals("James")){
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public static class User{
    private String name;
    private Integer grade;
}
```

result：[Test11.User(name=CJ, grade=98), Test11.User(name=Tom, grade=90), Test11.User(name=lucy, grade=85), Test11.User(name=James, grade=83)]

I want names equal to James to rank first, others in descending order of grade, and my ranking writing method can't reach the result I want.

Is there a good way to solve my problem??

Comment: You should return negative for `equals("James")` if you want these objects to appear at the beginning of the list.

Comment: So the problem was resolved?  Then this question is no longer needed, right? Or, you might refine it if want to ask something else.

Comment: yeap，problem was resolved。 return negative for equals("James")，That's right

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Returning an integer is redundant here. Returning the result of `equals` method would work just fine.

Comment: @ETO It seems like an answer to a question I've never asked. I've just pointed out why the code provided by PO yields incorrect results. It wasn't a suggestion of how to improve it.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko The spirit of SO community is to provide good answers instead of just falling into another [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that calling `sorted` multiple times is neither an efficient nor a reliable solution. First it repeats the sorting for the whole stream multiple times. Second it does not guarantee the correctness of sorting, especially when using parallel streams.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort existing list, then try this:

```java
list.sort(Comparator.<User, Boolean>comparing(u -> "James".equals(u.getName()))
                    .thenComparing(User::getGrade)
                    .reversed());
```

Here's how you can create a new sorted list using `Stream API`:

```java
List<User> sortedList = 
    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.<User, Boolean>comparing(u -> "James".equals(u.getName()))
                          .thenComparing(User::getGrade)
                          .reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```